# use google translate API to convert English into text Arabic text in java

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3

Following code i user to convert my string into Arabic

```
Translate.setHttpReferrer("http://localhost:8080/crmweb/");
    String arabicString = Translate.execute(englishString, Language.ENGLISH, Language.ARABIC);

    if(arabicString != null){
     System.out.println("This method return as arabic string ==============> ");
     return arabicString;
    }
```

This code work when i run application in main method , but when i tries to run it in web application it gives an error like -- `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/translate/Translate`

Answer (score 2):

The Google Translate API JARs need to be in the **WEB-INF/lib** directory of the web application.  This is true whether you're building and deploying a WAR file, or simply using a directory structure on disk.

This process is more basically known as "putting the dependency JARs in the webapp's classpath."